# Add string test to URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a production environment and a test environment. The customer has set up the test environment with different URL's like `http://intranet.company.com` and `http://intranettest.company.com`, which make perfect sense. The content in the test database is the same as in the production database, where we store a link that is used on the web page. I don't have access to the database and need to change the link from production to test environment

- `http://intranet.company.com` should be parsed to `http://intranettest.company.com`

There could be additional endings, such as `/sites/marketing` but without a file name (`default.aspx`). The link can also have a port specified (in my development environment, which is not really important for the question at large. The development link is `http://devenv:1337/sites/marketing` which might explain my strange code.

I've made a snippet, but it doesn't feel right, and I can see several problems later on - using it. Is there a better way than the following to edit my URL?

```
string SiteCollectionURL = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url.ToString();

char[] delimiterChar = {'/', '.'};
string[] splitSiteCollectionURL = SiteCollectionURL.Split(delimiterChar);
string[] splitDepartmentLinkURL = departmentLink.Split(delimiterChar);
string fixedUrl = departmentLink;

if (splitSiteCollectionURL[2].Contains("test"))
{
    fixedUrl = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < splitDepartmentLinkURL.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            fixedUrl += splitDepartmentLinkURL[i] + "//";
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            if (splitDepartmentLinkURL[i].Contains(":"))
            {
                string[] splitUrlColon = splitDepartmentLinkURL[2].Split(':');
                fixedUrl += splitUrlColon[0] + "test:" + splitUrlColon[1] + "/";
            }
            else
            {
                fixedUrl += splitDepartmentLinkURL[i] + "test" + ".";
            }
        }
        else if (i > 2 && i < 4)
        {
            fixedUrl += splitDepartmentLinkURL[i] + ".";
        }
        else if (i >= 4 && i != splitDepartmentLinkURL.Length - 1)
        {
            fixedUrl += splitDepartmentLinkURL[i] + "/";
        }
        else
        {
            fixedUrl += splitDepartmentLinkURL[i];
        }
    }
    departmentLink = fixedUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the problems you foresee? It would help if you explain them in your question. But take a look at the [UriBuilder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx):

```
var uris = new List<String>
{
    @"http://intranet.company.com",
    @"http://myhost.company.com:1337",
    @"http://intranet.company.com/deep/path?wat",
    @"http://myhost.company.com:1337/some/other?path",
};


foreach (var u in uris)
{
    var ub = new UriBuilder(u);
    ub.Host = "intranettest.company.com";
    ub.Port = 80;

    Console.WriteLine(ub.Uri);
}
```

Works for me:

```
http://intranettest.company.com/
http://intranettest.company.com/
http://intranettest.company.com/deep/path?wat
http://intranettest.company.com/some/other?path
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm not completely following but for the sake of getting this argument started :
Why not do

```
var newUrl = oldUrl.Replace(@"http://intranet.company.com", @"http://intranettest.company.com");
```